# How to create/write to a output channel only once?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm trying to learn how to create a vscode extension

theres a function that im printing some text to console, however each time the function
is called, it creates a new output channel:

```js
const channel = vscode.window.createOutputChannel("debug");
channel.show();
console.log("test");
```

how i could avoid it? I mean, create the channel only once.

Comment: Create a single instance in `activate` and then pass to elsewhere.

Comment: @LexLi how do i access the instance from outside the `activate`?

Comment: Your extension starts from that function, so you can pass it to any other functions from there as argument. Or if you prefer IoC, you can pass via injection, https://rpeshkov.net/blog/vscode-extension-di/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like with any other part you want to share in a JS/TS project, you have to export it. In my extension.ts I created the output channel in the `activate` function and provide an exported print function to access it:

```js
let outputChannel: OutputChannel;

export const activate = (context: ExtensionContext): void => {
    outputChannel = window.createOutputChannel("My Extension");
...
}

/**
 * Prints the given content on the output channel.
 *
 * @param content The content to be printed.
 * @param reveal Whether the output channel should be revealed.
 */
export const printChannelOutput = (content: string, reveal = false): void => {
    outputChannel.appendLine(content);
    if (reveal) {
        outputChannel.show(true);
    }
};
```

Now you can import `printChannelOutput` in any of your extension files and call it with the text you want to print.